# Error in objectgears query

Tags: objectgears

I am getting an error like: "Error: Invalid column name 'Col_7_5'.__Invalid column name 'Col_7_7'." after running a query that I have created and that used to work well. Do you know what this could cause?

Comment: Have any column names changed since the query stopped working? Can we see the query?

Answer (score 0):

This is cased by changing the underlying classes. You need to go to the query and generate it again. You may also need to change the query definition but maybe you just add a space to the query definition and query will work again.

Look at documentation: http://doc.objectgears.cz/Help.aspx?H=a_data_query